# How to show data for current (using dataset1) and last quarter(using dataset 2) in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, fetchxml

I need to show total number of cases open during current quarter(selected from parameter) and open cases in last quarter. I'm using different datasets with different conditions for my report. One dataset query should show cases based on the Quarter selected, for example Jan-Mar which is working fine. Another dataset query should show me the cases that were received by end of last quarter. For example, when I select Jan-Mar, it should display cases received by end of last quarter which is Dec 31st, 2021. How can I accomplish this? I could use 'on-or-before' operator in my fetchxml but Quarter is not a field in the database, it's a calculated field in SSRS.

Comment: For dataset1, I'm using =DatePart("q",Fields!received_date.Value) to get data for same quarter (selected from parameter, e.g. Jan-Feb) but dataset2 should display data for previous quarter-Oct-Dec 2021, how this can be done?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.